# Transform PHP script into executable

Tags: php, shell, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, executable

I am trying to create a script to upload my file to Google Drive. When I run it, it works perfectly. Here's the working code:

```php
public function uploadToDrive()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId(Mage::getStoreConfig('mtm_google/drive/client_id'));
    $client->setClientSecret(Mage::getStoreConfig('mtm_google/drive/client_secret'));
    $client->setRedirectUri(Mage::getStoreConfig('mtm_google/drive/redirect_uri'));
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));

    session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['code']) || (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])) {
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        } else {
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        }

        $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

        $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $file->setName('analysis.csv');
        $file->setDescription('A test document');
        $data = file_get_contents('temp.csv');

        $service->files->create($file, array(
            'data' => $data,
            'mimeType' => 'text/csv',
            'uploadType' => 'multipart'
        ));
        echo 'SUCCESS!';
        unlink('temp.csv');
    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
        exit();
    }
}
```

This script should be executable from console, and not executed from certain URL. When I try to execute this from console, nothing happens because session variables and redirects are something it can't handle. How can I modify this script in order to be executable from console?

Comment: eliminate any dependencies on things that'd only be available in a web environment? kill off $_SESSION, kill off `header()`, blah blah blah.

Comment: give me full code, i'll try it on my localhost

Comment: @Monty I already solved it (with different script), but truly appreciate effort. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply define/set variables : `$_GET, $_SESSION, ....`
Those variables can be passed like an arguments from console using `$argv[]`

Comment: But how can i automate them, when token is different every time? I cant hardcode its value?